# two different google streetviews

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-street-view

I am getting two different streetviews, and I'm wondering if anyone can help me understand why the difference occurs.

I start on google maps and zoom into the streetview with the following URL:

https://www.google.com/maps/place/452+42+Ave+SE/@51.0445,-114.059,3a,75y,346.38h,85.83t/data=!3m4!1e1!3m2!1smwjybt0aGjulRlrUl7QyMg!2e0!4m7!1m4!3m3!1s0x53717001e51c622d:0xe4cc541a8bac14f6!2s219+9+Ave+SE!3b1!3m1!1s0x0:0x22eaf82b58b21f94

I then extract the latitude and longitude and generate the following static streetview:

https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/streetview?size=600x600&location=(51.0445, -114.059)&sensor=false

However, when I compare the two views they are different.  Any ideas why?

Comment: not enough resolution in the [coordinates](https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/streetview?size=600x600&location=(51.044463,-114.058452)&sensor=false)

Comment: there are many differences, which do you mean exactly

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess you don't mean the size(of course it will differ, because static maps have a limited size )

Static maps have multiple parameters([documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/streetview/#url_parameters)):

1. **`location`**
       when I open the first link at least for me the location will be changed to `51.044463,-114.058452` .
2. **`heading`**
   for the first  link it's the parameter followed by a `h` : `346.38`
3. **`fov`**
   for the first link it's the parameter followed by a `y` :`75`
4. **`pitch`**
   for the first link it's the parameter followed by a `t` :`85.83`
   substract 90 from that value: `-4.17`

**Result:**  [`https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/streetview?size=600x600&location=%2851.044463,-114.058452%29&heading=346.38&fov=75&pitch=-4.17&sensor=false`](https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/streetview?size=600x600&location=%2851.044463,-114.058452%29&heading=346.38&fov=75&pitch=-4.17&sensor=false)

---

**Result without these parameters:**

### [image]

**Result with the parameters:**

[image]

---

**Screenshot for the first link(browserwindow resized to a viewport of 600x600)**

[image]