# How to know parameters for a street view embedding through Map Javascript API

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I have a google street view url that i want to embed using google map javascript API not with iframe. The url is https://www.google.com/maps/@40.4586024,3.6939102,3a,90y,300.49h,65.52t/data=!3m7!1e1!3m5!1s5IWj6M32jEwDMbJOp5mi8A!2e0!3e2!7i13312!8i6656?hl=en

But to embed a steet-view i need to know the exact parameters like Heading, Pitch, Latitude and Langitude, zoom etc.

Is there a way to get these?

Comment: In the settings overflow by the name of the place (top left), you should be able to get an embed link. I guess it's different from the actual Javascript library, but maybe you can parse that url for parameters. [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/387942/google-street-view-url) question can provide more details on the parameters.

Comment: Look at this post. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22979030/two-different-google-streetviews#new-answer